# How can I change the triangles vertices points to other geometric figures?

Tags: list-manipulation, replacement, geometry

I want to convert the triangle's vertices points into hexagons like in the image above, where all the distances are the same, a=1 for example.

[image]

I've tried to use TranslationTransform

```
hexagon = 
  N[{{0, 1/2} Sqrt[3], {Sqrt[3]/6, 1} Sqrt[3], {Sqrt[3]/2, 1} Sqrt[
     3], {(2 Sqrt[3])/3, 1/2} Sqrt[3], {Sqrt[3]/2, 0} Sqrt[
     3], {Sqrt[3]/6, 0} Sqrt[3]}];

rule[x_, y_] := Flatten[Table[{3 j, k}, {j, 0, x}, {k, 0, y}], 1];


points = Flatten[
   TranslationTransform[# - hexagon[[1]]][hexagon] & /@ rule[1, 0], 1];


g1 = Graphics[{EdgeForm[Thickness[0.001]], PointSize[0.009], Blue, 
    Point /@ points}];
Show[g1]
```

[image]

In the otherway, I'm trying to use a Nest function

```
sierpinski[{a_, b_, c_}] := 
  With[{ab = (a + b)/2, bc = (b + c)/2, 
    ca = (a + c)/2}, {{a, ab, ca}, {ab, b, bc}, {ca, bc, c}}];

pts = N[ {{0, 0}, {1, 0}, {1/2, Sqrt[3]/2}} ];
l = 2;
SG = Flatten[Nest[Join @@ sierpinski /@ # &, {pts}, l],1];
```

And replacing each point in the SG list by a hexagon. To reproduce something like this

[image]

I would like to get the {x,y} coordinates of each hexagon's point too

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Update:**

```
hexcoords = CirclePoints[6]/6;
```

Define transformation functions to translate the coordinates of a regular hexagon using the centroids of polygons in `SierpinskiMesh[n]`:

```
ClearAll[translation, replace, hexgrid]

translation[1] := TranslationTransform /@ (RegionCentroid /@ 
      Join[{#}, MeshPrimitives[#, 2]] & @ SierpinskiMesh[1])

translation[n_] := TranslationTransform /@
     (2^n (RegionCentroid /@ MeshPrimitives[SierpinskiMesh[n], 2]))

replace[n_] := ReplaceAll[{(prim : Polygon | Point)[x_] :>
     (prim /@ (# @ x & /@ translation[n]))}]

hex0 = {FaceForm[], EdgeForm[Gray], Polygon[hexcoords ], Blue, Point[hexcoords]};

hexgrid[n_, opts : OptionsPattern[]] := 
 Graphics[replace[n] @ If[n <= 1, Identity, replace[1]] @ hex0, opts]


Grid[{hexgrid[#, ImageSize -> 1 -> 50] & /@ Range[0, 3]}, 
 Alignment -> Bottom]
```

[image]

To get the polygon coordinates in `hexgrid[n]` use `Cases`:

```
Cases[hexgrid[1], Polygon[x_] :> x, All]
```

[image]

**Original answer:**

```
hex = CirclePoints[6];
tri = Sqrt[3] CirclePoints[3];

step1 = {FaceForm[], EdgeForm[Red], Polygon @ tri, Blue, 
   AbsolutePointSize[3], Point @ tri, 
   Translate[{FaceForm[], EdgeForm[Gray], Polygon @ hex, Blue, 
     AbsolutePointSize[3], Point @ hex}, tri]};

Graphics @ step1
```

[image]

```
Grid[{Graphics[#, ImageSize -> 1 -> 10] & /@ 
   FoldList[Translate[#, 2 #2 tri] &, step1, Range[3]]}, 
 Alignment -> Bottom]
```

[image]

Alternatively, without the triangles:

```
step0 = Translate[{FaceForm[], EdgeForm[Gray], Polygon@hex, Blue, 
    AbsolutePointSize[3], Point @ hex}, Append[Mean @ #] @ # & @ tri];

Graphics @ step0
```

[image]

```
Grid[{Graphics[#, ImageSize -> 1 -> 10] & /@ 
   FoldList[Translate[#, 2 #2 tri] &, step0, Range[3]]}, 
 Alignment -> Bottom]
```

[image]

Comment: How could I only get the coordinates of the hexagons without the triangle points

Comment: use `step1 = Translate[{FaceForm[], EdgeForm[Gray], Polygon@hex, Blue,     AbsolutePointSize[3], Point@hex}, tri];`?

Comment: I mean, the {x,y} coordinates of each point of the hexagons.

Comment: Maybe something like `n= 4;Fold[Join @@ Through[(TranslationTransform /@ (2 #2 tri))@#] &, hex,  Range[n]]`?

Comment: There is a overlap in the 4th order between the triangles in the base.

Comment: Now with this uptdate, how can we get the {x,y} coordinates?

Comment: @LucasLopes, please see the new version of the update.

Comment: Alright, now it works pretty well, and its easier for me to apply rotations working with hexcoords

Answer (score 5):

**Edit**

```
tri2hexpts[{a_, b_, c_}] := 
  Module[{e1, e2, hexpts, hex0, hex1, hex2, hex3}, e1 = (b - a)/3;
   e2 = (c - a)/3;
   hexpts = {{1, 0}, {2, 0}, {2, 1}, {1, 2}, {0, 2}, {0, 1}} . {e1, 
      e2};
   hex0 = TranslationTransform[a]@hexpts;
   hex1 = 
    TranslationTransform[a]@
     TranslationTransform[{-1, 2} . {e1, e2}]@hexpts;
   hex2 = 
    TranslationTransform[a]@
     TranslationTransform[{-1, -1} . {e1, e2}]@hexpts;
   hex3 = 
    TranslationTransform[a]@
     TranslationTransform[{2, -1} . {e1, e2}]@hexpts;
   {hex0, hex1, hex2, hex3}];
n = 4;
pts = TransformedRegion[#, 
      ScalingTransform[{.5, .5}, RegionCentroid[#]]] & /@ 
    MeshPrimitives[SierpinskiMesh[n], 2] // Flatten[#, 1] &;
groupts = MeshPrimitives[#, 0] & /@ pts /. Point -> Identity;
Graphics[{FaceForm[], EdgeForm[Gray], 
    Polygon /@ #, {Blue, AbsolutePointSize[2], Point /@ #}} & /@ 
  tri2hexpts /@ groupts]
```

[image]

If we want to rotate the triangle,we can define `tri2hexpts3`

```
tri2hexpts3 = tri2hexpts@RotationTransform[20 Degree, Mean[#]][#] &;
Graphics[{FaceForm[], EdgeForm[Gray], 
    Polygon /@ #, {Blue, AbsolutePointSize[2], Point /@ #}} & /@ 
  tri2hexpts3 /@ groupts]
```

[image]

**Original**

```
SeedRandom[244];
{a, b, c} = RandomReal[{-1, 1}, {3, 2}];
e1 = (b - a)/3;
e2 = (c - a)/3;
hexpts = {{1, 0}, {2, 0}, {2, 1}, {1, 2}, {0, 2}, {0, 1}} . {e1, e2};
{FaceForm[], EdgeForm[Green], Triangle[{a, b, c}], EdgeForm[Red], 
  Polygon@TranslationTransform[a]@hexpts, 
  Polygon@TranslationTransform[a]@
    TranslationTransform[{-1, 2} . {e1, e2}]@hexpts, 
  Polygon@TranslationTransform[a]@
    TranslationTransform[{-1, -1} . {e1, e2}]@hexpts, 
  Polygon@TranslationTransform[a]@
    TranslationTransform[{2, -1} . {e1, e2}]@hexpts} // Graphics
```

[image]

```
tri2hexpts[{a_, b_, c_}] := 
  Module[{e1, e2, hexpts, hex0, hex1, hex2, hex3}, e1 = (b - a)/3;
   e2 = (c - a)/3;
   hexpts = {{1, 0}, {2, 0}, {2, 1}, {1, 2}, {0, 2}, {0, 1}} . {e1, 
      e2};
   hex0 = TranslationTransform[a]@hexpts;
   hex1 = 
    TranslationTransform[a]@
     TranslationTransform[{-1, 2} . {e1, e2}]@hexpts;
   hex2 = 
    TranslationTransform[a]@
     TranslationTransform[{-1, -1} . {e1, e2}]@hexpts;
   hex3 = 
    TranslationTransform[a]@
     TranslationTransform[{2, -1} . {e1, e2}]@hexpts;
   {hex0, hex1, hex2, hex3}];
pts = tri2hexpts[CirclePoints[3]];
Graphics[{FaceForm[], EdgeForm[Gray], 
  Polygon /@ pts, {Blue, AbsolutePointSize[20], Point /@ pts}}]
```

```
SeedRandom[123];
ranpts = tri2hexpts[RandomReal[4, {3, 2}]];
Graphics[{FaceForm[], EdgeForm[Gray], 
  Polygon /@ ranpts, {Blue, AbsolutePointSize[20], Point /@ ranpts}}]
```

[image]

Comment: Do you see how we could grow the generation? An alternative besides the fact you can keep going creating hex4, hex5, .....

Comment: How could I get the {x,y} coordinates of the points? Also, I've tried to apply a RotationTransform by 90 Degrees in the hexagon points but it failed, do you have any guesses?

Comment: @LucasLopes `Flatten[tri2hexpts /@ groupts, 2]` are  all the points. `Flatten[tri2hexpts /@ groupts, 2] // Point // Graphics`

Comment: Where can I rotate the hexagons?

Comment: Here it is not working hexpts = RotationTransform[
    20 Degree, {0, 0}] /@ {{1, 0}, {2, 0}, {2, 1}, {1, 2}, {0, 2}, {0,
      1}}.{e1, e2}

Comment: @LucasLopes We should rotate the point `{a,b,c}` instead of change the base `{e1,e2}` and the coordinate ` {{1, 0}, {2, 0}, {2, 1}, {1, 2}, {0, 2}, {0, 1}}` For example, we can define `tri2hexpts2[{a_, b_, c_}] := 
 tri2hexpts[RotationTransform[20 Degree, {0, 0}] /@ {a, b, c}]` and replace `tri2hexpts` to `tri2hexpts2`.

Answer (score 3):

An alternative approach using [`MeshCellShapeFunction`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/MeshCellShapeFunction.html) to render polygons with the desired shape:

```
cp6 = CirclePoints[6]/6;
cp3 = Sqrt[3] CirclePoints[3]/6;

shape = {FaceForm[], EdgeForm[Gray], Blue, 
    {Polygon[# @ cp6], Point[# @ cp6]} & /@ 
       TranslationTransform /@ Join[{Mean @ cp3}, cp3]};

Graphics @ shape
```

[image]

```
ClearAll[meshCellShapeFunction]
meshCellShapeFunction[m_, shp_:shape] := ReplaceAll[{(prim : Polygon | Point)[x_] :>
    prim[#[2^-m x]]} & @ TranslationTransform[Mean @ #]] @ shp &;


sierpinskiHexMesh[n_] := SierpinskiMesh[n, 
  MeshCellShapeFunction -> {2 -> meshCellShapeFunction[n]}]

Multicolumn[
 Show[sierpinskiHexMesh @ #, ImageSize -> 400] & /@ Range[0, 3],
 2, Appearance -> "Horizontal"]
```

[image]

To extract the polygons we use  `meshCellShapeFunction[m]` on 2D mesh primitives of `sierpinskiHexMesh[m]` with `Cases`:

```
Cases[meshCellShapeFunction[0] @@@ 
  MeshPrimitives[SierpinskiMesh[0], 2], _Polygon, All]
```

[image]

Using non-default shapes to render 2D mesh cells:

```
SierpinskiMesh[5, 
 MeshCellShapeFunction -> {2 -> 
    meshCellShapeFunction[5, 
      {FaceForm[Opacity[.5, Red]], Polygon[3/4 CirclePoints[50]], 
      Green, Polygon[1/3 CirclePoints[50]], Black, Point[{0, 0}]}]}]
```

[image]

```
SierpinskiMesh[4, 
 MeshCellShapeFunction -> {0 -> ({Red, Annulus[#, .01]} &), 
   2 -> meshCellShapeFunction[4, {Blue, 
      Polygon[CirclePoints[{.4, Pi/2}, 5][[{1, 3, 5, 2, 4}]]]}]}]
```

[image]

An alternative way to use `meshCellShapeFunction` + `SierpinskiMesh` to get graphics primitives that can be used with `Graphics`:

```
Graphics[meshCellShapeFunction[3] @@@ 
  MeshPrimitives[SierpinskiMesh[3], 2]]
```

[image]

Comment: In the previous answer, how could I show the triangles like this Multicolumn[
 Show[sierpinskiHexMesh @ #, ImageSize -> 400] & /@ Range[0, 3],
 2, Appearance -> "Horizontal"]

Comment: try `Multicolumn[Graphics[#, ImageSize -> 300] & /@ 
  FoldList[Translate[#, 2 #2 tri] &, step0, Range[3]], 2, 
 Appearance -> "Horizontal", Spacings -> {5, 5}]`?

Comment: I was trying to make something similar to this with rotation https://gyazo.com/63509e8640bd03d794ade6e87ad2af92. 

What I have made with your code is use hexcoords = {{-0.123718, 0.}, {-0.247436, 0.0714286}, {-0.247436, 
  0.214286}, {-0.123718, 0.285714}, {0., 0.214286}, {0., 0.0714286}}

And use SierpinskiMesh[2] in translation[1], but with this I got something a little different from the case in the link above. What do you think?

Comment: @LucasLopes, use `hexcoords = CirclePoints[{1, Pi/2}, 6]/6;` and change `translation[1]` to `translation[1] :=  TranslationTransform /@ (Sqrt[3]/3 MeshCoordinates[
     SierpinskiMesh[1]])` add the line `replace[0] = Identity;`. Then `hexgrid[n]` should give the picture in [you linked to](https://gyazo.com/63509e8640bd03d794ade6e87ad2af92)